# Sorting KeystoneJS results by the count of a relationship field

Tags: node.js, postgresql, keystonejs

[Based on the docs](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/relationships#one-to-many), a one-to-many relationship can be configured as follows:

```
keystone.createList('User', {
  fields: {
    name: { type: Text },
    posts: { type: Relationship, ref: 'Post.author', many: true },
  },
});

keystone.createList('Post', {
  fields: {
    title: { type: Text },
    content: { type: Text },
    author: { type: Relationship, ref: 'User.posts', many: false },
  },
});
```

So each post is authored by one user, and each user can author many posts.

I can then get a count of how many posts each user has authored with the following query:

```
query {
  allUsers {
    id
    name
    _postsMeta {
      count
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to sort the result of this query by `_postsMeta { count }`? The [sortBy](https://www.keystonejs.com/guides/intro-to-graphql/#sortby) parameters available seem to be limited to non-relationship fields?